# Collision check with RayCast2D on tilemaps

Tags: python, collision, godot

I'm trying to make a simple 2D mining game in godot. I need to make RayCast2D to locate tiles but it just ignores them, so even the start of the script isn't working.
I checked, raycast is enabled and looking in the right direction.
Here is the script I use to check if raycast collides.

```
func tile_finding():
   if is_colliding():
      print("ok")
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach a collision shape to each tile (in the tileset panel) you are interested in checking collision with. Next they need to share the same collision layer. have you enabled the raycast2D setting the `enabled` property?

the collision handling using tilemap uses code like this:

```
if is_colliding():
    var hit_collider = get_collider()
    if hit_collider extends TileMap:
        var tilemap = hit_collider
        var hit_pos = get_collision_point()
        var tile_pos = tilemap.world_to_map(hit_pos)
        var tile_id = tilemap.get_cellv(tile_pos)
        # whatever you want
```